# Unexpected results for mathematical operations

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

While performing mathematical operations to develop an android application for  a simple calculator, resulted in strange results for subtraction and division  operation. Other operations goes well with the inputs provided. In my research  for precision handling, came across BigDecimal class that lessen down my  errors.

Certain operations like subtraction and division have not yielded proper  results. I am providing with the code snippet here.

```
.
.
.
String answer = "";
BigDecimal bigDecimal1, bigDecimal2;
BigDecimal bigDecimalResult;
String operation = "";
.
.
.

                case R.id.button_substraction:
                    bigDecimal1 = new BigDecimal(answer);
                    operation = "-";
                    answer = "";
                    textViewAnswer.setText(buttonSubstraction.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button_division:
                    bigDecimal1 = new BigDecimal(answer);
                    operation = "/";
                    answer = "";
                    textViewAnswer.setText(buttonDivision.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button_equal:
                    bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal(answer);
                    answer = "";
                    switch (operation) {
                           .
                           .

                        case "-":
                            bigDecimalResult = (bigDecimal1.subtract(bigDecimal2)).setScale(6,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
                            textViewAnswer.setText(bigDecimalResult.toString());
                            break;

                        case "/":
                            bigDecimalResult = (bigDecimal1.divide(bigDecimal2)).setScale(6,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
                            textViewAnswer.setText(bigDecimalResult.toString());
                            break;
                    }
.
.
.
```

Example:

1. Subtraction

when a number is subtracted from itself, it results 0 with the precision value 6(set in the code) as,

100 - 100 = 0.000000

Even though stripTrailingZeros() is specified.

2. Division

Attempting to divide

1 / 9

crashes my app.

- Have I gone wrong with logic implementation ?
- Does it has something to do with storage representation in memory as BigDecimal class is used ?

Comment: Hint: you expect us to help; so you start with making that as easy as possible; for example by proper formatting of your source code. Then: such kind of code is **perfect** for unit testing; and ideally you would show give us code samples that a) compile and b) exactly repro the unexpected results.

Comment: @Jägermeister the reason to post limited code is to limit the complexity of the problem. all the necessary information related to the problem is included within the code. I will make sure to work on your suggestions that you have pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `stripTrailingZeros()` not stripping a zero value was fixed in Java 8.
See [JDK-6480539: BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros() has no effect on zero itself ("0.0")](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6480539)

Your problem with `1 / 9` crashing your app, is caused by your logic:

```
bigDecimalResult = bigDecimal1.divide(bigDecimal2)
                              .setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                              .stripTrailingZeros()
```

You are trying to set the scale *after* dividing, but there is no exact value for `1 / 9`, so the [`divide()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)) method throws an exception, as documented in the javadoc.

> Throws `ArithmeticException` if the exact quotient does not have a terminating decimal expansion

You should call one of the other overloads of the [`divide()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) method:

```
bigDecimalResult = bigDecimal1.divide(bigDecimal2, 6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                              .stripTrailingZeros()
```

---

Now, beware result of `stripTrailingZeros()`. E.g. if result is `100.00000`, `stripTrailingZeros()` will literally strip *all* the zeros, resulting in `1E+2`. That is probably not what you want.

To get that printed in a more human readable way, you might want to use [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) instead of [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()).

Comment: running on the latest version of java. stripTrailingZeros() still returns to be non-expected behaviour.

Comment: I'm running jdk1.8.0_91, and output is `0` for me when I run `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.00000").stripTrailingZeros().toString())`

Comment: using android studio for development, that might be the case for failure.. goes pretty good when I run as a java program.